# Can I use Spring to develop a server that Manages workflows

Tags: java, spring, serversocket

I am using the Spring framework on a project.

I need to develop a server that starts and stops by the introduction of script shell commands (`sh -start` & `sh -stop`).

The server should always running and waiting for commands from the user.

Also the server manages the execution of a number of workflows  based on a Context at the same time  .

I wonder if Spring can do that or is there any other framework or technology to simplify my Task .

Comment: Please clarify, are you writing a web application or a standalone java server ? Spring is quite a huge framework, some parts are geared towards web applications, some others are pretty neutral.

Comment: introduce yourself in JMX

Comment: @ BigMike :  I'm writing a Web Application :)

Comment: Spring is a framework whose primary function is to reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to write, allowing you to focus on the primary goals on the project. Whilst it does have some more application-specific modules, such as MVC for Servlet web apps, it does not have a focus on the specific type of application you want to write. Certainly Spring can be used in your project, but you might want a more applications-specific framework too, like JMX.

Comment: About The server haw can i make it always running and what is the Listnener that i should use to use the start and stop commands

Comment: If you're writing a web application, an application server is probably involved (glassfish, tomcat, jboss or something commercial), managemente of server is tied to that.